# biblatex: generate [ABC+99] instead of [Ali+99]

Tags: biblatex

I am switching from bibtex to biblatex and notice that,
for a paper with four authors, the citation is no longer `[ABC+99]`,
the initials of the first three authors.
Instead, it becomes `[Ali+99]`, where Alice is the first surname.

Question: How to generate `[ABC+99]`?

MWE:
`alphacite.bib`:

```
@misc{ABCD99,
    author = {A. Alice and B. Bob and C. Cindy and D. Dick},
    title = {How to use biblatex properly},
    year = {2099},
}
```

`alphacite.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
        \addbibresource{alphacite.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{ABCD99}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

P.S. I am not talking about `maxalphanames` as I don't want `[ABCD99]`.

Comment: Which style did you use with bibtex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want to change what happens with more than three authors, it is not enough to set `maxalphanames`, you also need to set `minalphanames`. The rules are that lists longer than `maxalphanames` are truncated to contain only `minalphanames` (+ et al.). If you want three names for + et al. for a four-name list, you need to change `minalphanames` from its default 1 to 3.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  minalphanames=3, maxalphanames=3,
  maxbibnames=999,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,companion,yoon,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR98; GMS94; YRK+06; Nus78]]

Comment: Thank you so much.  The documentation is useless and I would never have guessed that.

Comment: @Symbol1 It is a truth universally acknowledged that the `biblatex` documentation could be improved, yes. But I feel that calling it useless disparages the work Philipp Lehman and PLK have put not only into `biblatex`, but also in the documentation. ...

Comment: ... In fact the documentation says something every similar to what I said: If you look up `maxalphanames` you find "Similar to the `maxnames` option but customizes the format of the `labelalpha` field." Look up `maxnames` to find "A threshold affecting all lists of names [...]. If a list exceeds this threshold, i.e., if it holds more than `<integer>` names, it is automatically truncated according to the setting of the `minnames` option.".

Comment: Suggestions for improvement can always be shared at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: Sorry for my language.